# Generic Combobox for easier retrieval of selected item

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I got tired of always writing code to parse out the information associated with a Combo box getText() method.   So I wrote the following, free to use, enjoy.

If someone else has already done this, well I couldn't find it :-)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;

 /**
 * A generic wrapper around a standard SWT {@link Combo} control.
 * Allows for using arbitrary data objects associated with the displayed text.
 * Assumes a {@link SWT#READ_ONLY} combo drop list<br><br>
 * <blockquote>Combo peopleCombo = new Combo(shell, SWT.READ_ONLY);<br>
 * ComboControl&lt;Person&gt; peopleControl = new ComboControl&lt;Person&gt;(peopleCombo);<br><br>
 * for ( Person person : People.getPeople())<br>
 * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;peopleControl.addItem(person, person.getLastName);<br>
 * <br>
 * ...<br>
 * <br>
 * Person person = peopleControl.getCurrentItem();</blockquote> 
*/
public class ComboControl<T>
{
private ArrayList<ComboItem<T>> ivItemList;
private Combo                   ivCombo;

/**
 * Create a ComboControl for the passed Combo control
 * @param combo - SWT {@link Combo} control
 */
public ComboControl( Combo combo )
{
    super();

    ivCombo = combo;
    ivItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    removeAll();
}

/**
 * Adds an item to the controller along with the text you want shown in the Combo
 * @param itemData - the data item of the defined type
 * @param text - the text which will be shown in the Combo control
 */
public void addItem( T itemData, String text )
{
    // these are added at the same time, and therefore have the same index location
    ivItemList.add( new ComboItem<T>( itemData, text ) );
    ivCombo.add( text );
}

/**
 * Removes all the items in the list and Combo
 */
public void removeAll()
{
    ivItemList.clear();
    ivCombo.removeAll();
}

/**
 * Returns the combo held by this control
 */
public Combo getCombo()
{
    return ivCombo;
}

/**
 * Set the current displayed item in the Combo using the associated data object
 * @param setItemData - Sets the Combo display to the text associated with the setItemData
 */
public void setCurrentItem( T setItemData )
{
    for (ComboItem<T> item : ivItemList)
        if (item.getItemData().equals( setItemData ))
        {
            ivCombo.setText( item.getText() );
            return;
        }

    if (ivItemList.size() > 0)
        ivCombo.setText( ivItemList.get( 0 ).getText() );
}

/**
 * Gets the currently chosen ComboItem associated with the Combo control displayed text
 * @return the data item associated with the displayed text
 */
public T getCurrentItem()
{
    ComboItem<T> currentItem;

    try
    {
        currentItem = ivItemList.get( ivCombo.getSelectionIndex() );
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        try
        {
            currentItem = ivItemList.get( 0 );
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e1)
        {
            // will only happen if this method is called before there are any items in the list
            return null;
        }
    }

    return currentItem.getItemData();
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
    String className;

    try
    {
        className = getCurrentItem().getClass().getName();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        className = "";
    }

    info.append( "ComboControl (" );
    info.append( className );
    info.append( "):" );

    for (ComboItem<T> item : ivItemList)
    {
        info.append( "\n  " );
        info.append( item.getInformation() );
    }

    return info.toString();
}

/**
 * The item holding both the Combo control text, and its associated data
 */
private class ComboItem<I>
{
    private String ivText;
    private I      ivItemData;

    /**
     * Create the Combo item using the arbitrary data and the text to be displayed
     */
    private ComboItem( I itemData, String text )
    {
        super();

        ivItemData = itemData;
        ivText = text;
    }

    /**
     * Get the text to be displayed in the Combo control
     */
    private String getText()
    {
        return ivText;
    }

    /**
     * Get the object associated with the text shown in the Combo control
     */
    private I getItemData()
    {
        return ivItemData;
    }

    /**
     * Gets information about the item and its data item
     */
    private String getInformation()
    {
        return ivText + ": " + ivItemData.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Ok, so the StackOverflow question dohicky wants more non-code text to balance out the code. Well, here that is. I just need to keep adding text until it is happy. There should be some way of over-riding it, maybe a check box that I really REALLY want to have mostly code, because hey, that's just the way it is. Ahh, that seems to be enough :-)

Comment: Rather than putting everything in the question, you should write a question and then answer your own question.

Comment: Seriously? You give me a down-mark because of the comment/code ratio? Nothing about the actual content? Also, answering your own question is frowned upon on some boards.

Comment: Whoever gave you a downvote probably didn't do so because of how much code you have, it's because you don't have an actual question that people can answer. And it's okay here - encouraged actually - if you answer your own questions - in fact, as I found out recently, there's an option to submit an answer along with your question right when you post it.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, I thought it was you. Yes it was not a question, but I tried to be helpful. Sigh...

Comment: It’s great that you’re trying to help people- don’t be discouraged. Just edit your question a bit or make a new one and you’re good to go. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Ok, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477570/how-to-easily-get-a-data-reference-from-an-swt-combo-drop-list)